# DBAN fails on brand new laptop. What's wrong?

Tags: laptop, crash, dell-latitude, dban

I just got a few new Dell Latitude E5500 laptops.  I'm trying to wipe their hard drives using [DBAN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/) 1.0.7.

DBAN boots up, I type `zero` at the prompt, and it gets to the "loading dwipe" part just fine.

Instead of showing progress and wiping the drive, it just dies out and states,

> DBAN finished with non-fatal errors.
>
> This is usually caused by disks with bad sectors.
>
> Send the log file with all support requests.

This happens on all of the *brand new*, fresh out of the package laptops.  What the heck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten a DBAN 2.0.0 beta working.  The laptops are wiping away just like I was hoping they would.

It appears that there is [an incongruity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/forums/forum/208932/topic/3405355) between the sourceforge project page and the author's own site.

Apparently the most recent beta was [released](http://www.dban.org/download) on April 29, 2007, and is now available from [dban.org](http://www.dban.org).

Answer (score 2):

change the controller mode in the BIOS from AHCI to IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps DBAN doesn't include the drivers for that computer's hard drive. I've had that problem before but I forget the exact error message I got.

Comment: Unlikely, if it got that far.

Answer (score 0):

You either have

- a partition table that doesn't exactly reflect the true size of your hard drive, or
- bad sectors.

Find out for sure. Read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/5809/deleting-files-in-windows-xp-extremely-slow/71632#71632) on how to check for bad sectors.