# Software to find firmware of hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, firmware

does anyone know of a tool that can display the firmware of a hard disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/5809/deleting-files-in-windows-xp-extremely-slow) I list the major vendors' utilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look for a software utility provided by the manufacturer of your hard drive. I would not expect to find a way to query the firmware version that isn't specific to a manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Device Manager can give up some useful information.

Under Device Manager the detailed properties for my cd-rom it drive shows the full ID string that my drive reports to windows and I know for a fact that the latest firmware is DW10, as reported by the drive.  As you can see I'm on the Details tab, with the property "Device Instance Path"

It could be your drive does something similar.  Sorry I couldn't check my hard drives for this though, they're hidden behind a RAID array.

[image: Device manager details]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `wmic diskdrive` at the command prompt, for example `wmic diskdrive get model,firmwarerevision,serialnumber` to list the model, firmware, and serial numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the driver for a hard disk then that is available from Control Panel -> System -> Hardware -> Device Manager -> Disk Drives -> Driver.

Comment: -1. Modern hard drives do, in fact, have firmware.  If you visit the website of a hard drive manufacturer (Seagate, Western Digital, etc.) you'll often find firmware updates.

Comment: Really, I guess I have been out of the hardware game for a while now.