# System not functioning properly

Tags: operating-systems

My system configuration is as follows which is 3 months old : 
G31 Motherboad
3.1 GHZ AMD Athlon Processor
2 GB Dynet RAM
500 GB WD hard disk
N Computing X550 PCI Card.

Issue : When I start my system its takes a long time also the none of the services are in started state. When tried to start it throws an error message : taking long time etc...

Steps taken till now :

1) Formatted the root drive many times but only it works for that moment again I face the same issue as soon as the system reboots. 
2) Also tried repairing the OS, but it wokrs maximum of 1 hour again I start facing the same issue.
3) Tried scanning all the drives with McAfee 8.7I and got around 90 viruses (Desktop.ini) from drive (Not the root drive). All the viruses were deleted. Still the issue was not solved. 
4) I deleted all the partition in the drive formatted the disks fully and installed an fresh copy but again I faced an similar issue when I rebooted the system. Also found some different issue on the harddisk i.e. when we delete all the partition there should only 1 unpartitioned drive but in my case there were 2 unpartitioned drive (1 was the root drive and other). Set up was not allowing me to increase the root drive disk space neither it was allowing me to install the OS on other unpartitioned drive.

Suspecting that there might me issue with hardisk, I just replaced my harddisk with an spare one which is ony 40 GB. After installing an fresh copy of XP SP2 again the system stuck with the similar issue.

COULD ANYONE PLEASE GUIDE ME TO PROPER WAY ? WHERE AM I GOING WRONG ?

Answer (score 1):

Strip your system down to bare essentials: motherboard, cpu, ram, video, keyboard and mouse. In particular remove all other USB devices.

Test your system memory with a bootable CD using [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) .

Test your hard drive on a system using the [manufacturer's test utility.](https://superuser.com/questions/5809/deleting-files-in-windows-xp-extremely-slow/71632#71632)

If your hardware is stable, see if you are getting re-infected by the same source. Perhaps your are downloading the same problematic malware each time you re-install the O/S.

**Update:** If possible, remove the X550 card. It is the most unusual and complicating part in your system. If you must have it, be sure and load the latest drivers during that first bootup after re-installing the O/S.

I put a link in to Memtest86+ above. The simplest way to run it is to find a Linux boot CD, most of them (Red Hat, Ubuntu) have Memtest86+ as a boot option. Simply boot the CD, select memtest, and let run for 12 or more hours.

If you can't find a Linux boot CD, if you have access to a working computer with Internet, you can download a bootable image and either burn a bootable CD-R or boot from a USB Thumb Drive.

Comment: HI, 

Could you mention it in step by step process and how to do it ?

Comment: Sure thing, see Update in answer above.